# Cannot import tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I have tried to import tensorflow-gpu and I'm getting the same error with different versions of CUDA and cuDNN.
My GPU is compatible with CUDA and I have no problems installing but when I try to import tensorflow-gpu I got this:

ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Tensorflow version: 1.11
CUDA version: 10
cudNN: 7.3.1

I also tried cudaNN 5.0 because I saw on a forum that worked for some people.

Comment: Can you point which version of tensorflow you installed and which version of CUDA are you using?

Comment: Then write the solution so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: I tried it and didn't work

Comment: Did you wrote `import tensorflow-gpu` or `import tensorflow` cause both are imported with same statement.

Comment: I wrote import tensorflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your nvidia drivers installed properly, refer to this table to check out which CUDA and cuDNN version you should be using for the tensorflow version you prefer.

[image: tensorflow-cuda-cudnn-compatible]

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands in your cmd window

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;%PATH%

SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64;%PATH%

SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\include;%PATH%

SET PATH=C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%
```

also see the chart that Jialer Chew gave if you are now doing it use tf version 2.2.0 cuda version 10.1 and cudnn version 7.6.0.