# Tensorflow session failed to start! Cuda virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, ubuntu

So im trying to make tensorflow run on my computer. I successfully installed ubuntu, cuda, cudnn and anaconda and set a environment for tensorflow GPU. I have the lastest nvidia drivers available for my gtx 970m. 
This is the code i ran to test my program:

```html
<pre><font color="#8AE234"><b>alejandro@alejandro-GL502VT</b></font>:<font color="#729FCF"><b>~</b></font>$ conda activate tensorflow_gpuenv
(tensorflow_gpuenv) <font color="#8AE234"><b>alejandro@alejandro-GL502VT</b></font>:<font color="#729FCF"><b>~</b></font>$ python
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 17:14:51) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type &quot;help&quot;, &quot;copyright&quot;, &quot;credits&quot; or &quot;license&quot; for more information.
&gt;&gt;&gt; import tensorflow as tf
&gt;&gt;&gt; hello = tf.constant(&apos;Hello Stack Overflow!!&apos;)
&gt;&gt;&gt; sess = tf.Session()
2018-10-03 23:23:05.722821: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-10-03 23:23:05.804766: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:897] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-10-03 23:23:05.805564: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 970M major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.038
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 2.95GiB freeMemory: 2.57GiB
2018-10-03 23:23:05.805579: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-10-03 23:23:05.805780: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:158] Internal: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;&lt;stdin&gt;&quot;, line 1, in &lt;module&gt;
  File &quot;/home/alejandro/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpuenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py&quot;, line 1494, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File &quot;/home/alejandro/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpuenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py&quot;, line 626, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSession(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
</pre>
```

and here is my driver info

```html
<pre>+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.48                 Driver Version: 390.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 970M    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P8     7W /  N/A |    334MiB /  3024MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       980      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           227MiB |
|    0      1248      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         102MiB |
|    0      2671      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+</pre>
```

Comment: it says `CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version`. Could you please specify the details of things you have installed? ubuntu, tensorflow-gpu, nvidia driver, cuda, cudnn. Usually these are the ones messing up the installation. Check out [this table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578576/cannot-import-tensorflow-gpu/52584010#52584010) to make sure you are using the right versions.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, all the lastest versions of everything. I investigated a little and i saw maybe tensorflow doensn't work with CUDA lastest version yet. is that possible?

Comment: yes you're right. the latest CUDA (10 at this point) doesn't work with tensorflow. I personally follow Steps 2, 3, 4 on [this guide](https://medium.com/codezillas/step-by-step-guide-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-6feceb0df5c0). Let me know if it works then I will post it as an answer.

Comment: That's the guide I used, i might have upgraded cuda with apt upgrade or other command. Do you think i should star with a clean OS or just re install cuda? and what actions should i avoid to prevent it from upgrading?. I appreciate

Comment: I installed cuda manually using installer so apt upgrade wouldnt affect it. Download the installer from cuda site instead of installing from package managers.

Comment: You can try with removing cuda and reinstalling, it should work fine, at least for me

Comment: cuda 10 will not work with driver 390.48.  You should do a proper install of CUDA and verify it before moving on to other things, such as trying to use TF with it.

Comment: Check the CUDA toolkit compatibility version with Nividia driver [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility__table-toolkit-driver). Install accordingly. Thanks!